# Collapsing related datapoints in different (but sequential) rows into a single row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a CSV dataset that's generated by electronic means, but because the packets have discrete datapoints they are on different rows due to different timestamps. The goal is to chart this out.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wIfS.jpg

I would like to collapse the data so that all related values within a specific timeframe are on the same row. I don't care about a span of a few milliseconds. For example, rows 2 through 8 can all be in the same row, and then I can have a new row for rows 9 through 14. In this sense one of the columns could be the "master" at which point when a number comes in it indicates a new row is to be collected, and if there are multiple values for the same field within that cadence then the last one would be the one to stay.

For example, I could determine that "Speed" is master, so in this case rows 5 through 17 would be together. There are two values for Battery Power in rows 9 and 15, I could just discard row 9.

Is there a way that I could do this in Excel through pivots or some sort of bucketing system, through Excel scripting, or is there a more effective way?

Comment: sounds like you can use the `=maxifs()` formula.

Comment: Could you please [Edit] your post & add some  expected output !!

Comment: If " "Speed" is master, so in this case rows 5 through 17 would be together .." , for this.. the value for Battery Power will use row 9 or row 15 ?